# merging two war files with overlays

Tags: maven, merge, glassfish, overlay, war

I have to merge two war files. I use eclipse indigo and maven 2. So I put one war as a dependency in the others `pom.xml` and added the overlay option as well:

```
...
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
   <overlays>
    <overlay>
     <groupId>org.mydomain</groupId>
     <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    </overlay>
   </overlays>
 ...
```

I use this to add all dependencies as jar's to my lib folder:

```
 ...
 </configuration>
 </plugin>
  <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
     <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
```

So if I perform maven install a proper war file is build with everything in it. The problem is when I deploy this on the glassfish server (3.1) there are no classes deployed (I looked in the eclipseApps folder in my glassfish folder). The jar's are there, the folders are there but empty. So it does not work on the server.
Anyone an idea?

Update:
As proposed in the comments I put the war file in the autodeploy folder and got the following errors:

```
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.0 (FCS 2.1.0-b11) for context ''
INFO: Unsanitized stacktrace from failed start...
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:     com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document     'bundle://237.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': null
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:675)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:322)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4690)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5305)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:500)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:364)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
 Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:     Unable to parse document 'bundle://237.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': null
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:673)
... 19 more
 Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://237.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': null
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:923)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:868)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:659)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:2842)
at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:2828)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ParserConfigurationSettings.addRecognizedFeatures(ParserConfigurationSettings.java:115)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getBuilderForSchema(ConfigManager.java:1133)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getDocument(ConfigManager.java:1002)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:914)
... 23 more

SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:379)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4690)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5305)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:500)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
at     com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:364)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:2842)
at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:2828)
at     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ParserConfigurationSettings.addRecognizedFeatures(ParserConfigurationSettings.java:115)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getBuilderForSchema(ConfigManager.java:1133)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getDocument(ConfigManager.java:1002)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:914)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:868)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:659)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:322)
... 18 more

SEVERE: PWC1306: Startup of context  failed due to previous errors
SEVERE: PWC1305: Exception during cleanup after start failed
```

Comment: Why are you configuring the JAR plugin? This is a WAR project. The War plugin will merge all dependencies for you. Inspect the final war file, if it's fine. There is something wrong with your deployment.

Comment: As I wrote before the final war is complete. The structure of the project is like this:
myproject is the parent and has all the beans with it's dependencies. Some of these dependencies are from the same project but other packages (we have a flat hierarchy). Without the jar plugin there are not in the war. 
The second tier is mywebproject which contains the jsf stuff. I will use different webproject later which all use myproject (the framework) as a dependency. 
The problem is I cannot see where the deployment goes wrong.

Comment: You were right. I can put the jar plugin out of the pom. But still having the deployment problem. I figured out that I have no webapp-cache.xml in my target/war folder. May this be the problem?

Comment: Since you use Eclipse und Maven, make sure that you have the latest m2eclipse with WTP extension since this one does the way overlay for eclipse. About the `webapp-cache.xml` I can't tell if this is something GlassFish specific issue. Make a test deployment to Tomcat from within Eclipse.

Comment: Ok, I tried the update but it did not help...

Comment: If you build the WAR file and deploy manually to GlassFish, does this work for you?

Comment: Ok, I put the war in the autodeploy folder from glassfish. It seems the beans are loaded and registered, but I got a lot of other errors I never had before. I will put them in the main post.

Comment: The exception says that the jsf.xml is not ok. Check that.

Comment: There is no such thing as a jsf.xml (or I cannot find it). Maybe it is generated during deployment?